# Why the shell does not terminate when pressing Ctrl+C on the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

When the shell is not running any process, if I press `Ctrl+C` on the terminal, the shell will not terminate. Is this simply because the shell ignores the `SIGINT` signal, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 2):

The shell ignores `ctrl-C` so that other programs that the shell is running can catch it. An `EOF` on a blank line exits (`ctrl-D` in *nix, `ctrl-Z` in Windows).

Comment: You mean if a process ignores the `SIGINT` signal, then this signal will go to its child process?

Comment: @Steve I think it is specific to interactive shell sessions. The shell is an interpreter, so anything you type is going through the shell to your program. The shell delivers keyboard interrupts intact, because in an interactive environment, programs may be expecting them, but in any other environment they won't.

Comment: No, I don't think anything goes through the shell, for example if the shell executed the `cat` program, then anything I type into the terminal is going directly to the `cat` program without going through the shell first (Assuming you mean by "shel" programs like `bash` and `sh`).